# How to sort dollar number ranges in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort dollar ranges in JavaScript. The problem is that the response values are ordered like so

```
['$10,000 - $29,999', '$30,000 - $49,999', '$5,000 - $9,999', '$50,000+', 'Lower than $5,000']

needs to be sorted to

['Lower than $5,000', '$5,000 -$9,999', '$10,000 - $29,999', '$30,000 - $49,999', '$50,000+']
```

I would like to sort this in ascending order like so, but I would also want it to be robust in a sense that if the API ever changes the order it sends this data, it still maintains the same sorting:

Is there a way I can do this without hardcoding the sorting algorithm?

Comment: Can the ranges change in time or would they be the same everytime?

Comment: *"without hardcoding the sorting algorithm?"* You can use JavaScript's build-in `sort` method/algorithm, you just have to provide a callback that lets JavaScript know how to compare those values. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort .

Comment: Please show your best attempt at solving this problem yourself and explain what went wrong (errors, unexpected results, etc.)

Comment: @Shidersz The ranges will remain constant throughout time

Comment: Are values always going to have same structure, lowest having lower than $x,x, highest $x,x+ and all between $x,x -$x,x. If yes than that could be good guide for sort function callback

Comment: If the ranges aren't going to change maybe it can just be hardcoded instead of sorting the response from the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could try this:

```js
    let r = ['$10,000 - $29,999', '$30,000 - $49,999', '$5,000 - $9,999', '$50,000+', 'Lower than $5,000'];

    r.sort((a, b) => {
      return parseInt(a.match(/\$\d+,\d+/gi).pop().replace(/\D/gi, ""), 10) - parseInt(b.match(/\$\d+,\d+/gi).pop().replace(/\D/gi, ""), 10);
    });
    console.log(r);
```

**Explanation**:

1. Removing every character that is not a digit
2. Parse it into a number
3. Compare it

***Edit***:

I've edited my code in response to comment (I know it's not the prettiest code but it works)

Comment: you should `split()` on the `-` and drop the second number off before doing the `parseInt`

Comment: Not all elements of the array have a `-`, though.  It might be better to look at only the digit characters that follow the last `$` in the string...

Answer (score 1):

If your `ranges` will be preserved in the time, you can create an object to maintain a relation between the `ranges` and an assigned order. Then later you can use this object in the [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method:

```js
const rangeOrder = {
  'Lower than $5,000': 0,
  '$5,000 - $9,999': 1,
  '$10,000 - $29,999': 2,
  '$30,000 - $49,999': 3,
  '$50,000+': 4,  
}

let input =  ['$10,000 - $29,999', '$30,000 - $49,999', '$5,000 - $9,999', '$50,000+', 'Lower than $5,000'];

console.log(input.sort(
  (a, b) => rangeOrder[a] - rangeOrder[b]
));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Another solution, to avoid harcoding the ranges, can be using a custom function to match the maximun range value on every string.

```js
let input =  ['$10,000 - $29,999', '$30,000 - $49,999', '$5,000 - $9,999', '$50,000+', 'Lower than $5,000'];

const matchValue = (str) =>
{
    let matches = str.match(/\d+,\d+/g);
    let maxVal = matches.length > 1 ? matches[1] : matches[0];
    return +(maxVal.replace(",", ""));
}

input.sort((a, b) => matchValue(a) - matchValue(b));
console.log(input);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Your solution certainly does the job, but i think the OP said without hardcoding the sorting algorithm

Comment: @WebRookie Your right, I have added an alternative solution also.